# Guardar dirección de sensor ds18b20 en variable goblal

Tags: arduino

como dice el titulo necesito almacenar el la dirección de un sensor de temperatura DS18B20 en una variable global para después enviarla por puerto serie como identificador.
Para explicarme mejor lo que tengo que hacer es  una cadena que sea  de esta forma "dirección_sensor,Temperatura", con el tema de la temperatura ya no tengo problema pero si con almacenar la dirección del sensor

Esté es el código que uso para saber la dirección del sensor

```
void printAddress(DeviceAddress deviceAddress){
  char result;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    if (deviceAddress[i] < 16){
    Serial.print("0");
  }
  Serial.print(deviceAddress[i], HEX);
}
```

el tema es que si logro tener por Serial.print la dirección del sensor pero necesito pero necesito guardarla en una variable Global

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Declara `deviceAddress` como variable global y elimina el parámetro en la función `printAddress`. Con eso, todo el sketch tendra acceso a la variable.

```
DeviceAddress deviceAddress;

void setup() {
...
}

void loop() {
...
}

void printAddress(){
  char result;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    if (deviceAddress[i] < 16){
    Serial.print("0");
  }
  Serial.print(deviceAddress[i], HEX);
}
```